# Integral Time and KI in PID

Tags: pid-controller

I am working on drive to control the speed of motor using software ***PID***. the output of ***PID*** will generate the reference for drive to run at particular speed. Here ***Kp*** and ***Kd*** will come from drive it self. The problem I am facing is that drive is giving ***integral time(Ti)*** instead of ***integral gain(Ki***. How do I do the integral part if I have ***integral time(Ti)*** but not the ***integral gain(Ki)***?

Answer (score 3):

Various forms of the PID equation are possible, but from your description it appears you have: \$(K_p + 1/T_i s + K_ds)\$. Generally, \$K_i = 1/T_i\$.

Other common forms are: \$(K_p + K_i/s + K_ds)\$ ; \$K_p(1 + 1/T_i s + T_d s)\$

Arguably, the most useful form is: \$ \frac{K_p (1 + T_i s + T_i T_d s^2)} {T_i s} \$ as this is the easiest to build into a transfer function, and also the proportional gain operates on all three terms and is identifiable as a 'loop gain'. This form is also very useful in root locus analysis as it clearly identifies the PID's open loop pole, at \$s=0\$, and two open loop zeros, with the integral and derivative times, \$T_i\$ and \$T_d\$, allowing the zeros to be placed at appropriate positions in the s-plane.

Comment: Can I use ***Kp(Ts/Ti)*** . Where ***Ts*** is my sampling time and ***Ti*** is my integral time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you want to implement this digitally, convert the s-TF into a z-TF and then form a difference equation. The bilinear transform is a good method for \$s\rightarrow z\$ transformation. Alternatively, term-by-term discretization also works well for PID.